# Find the general term of this series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was solving problems of a text named mathematical anaysis. I reached portion to check convergence using ratio test. I met with a series 
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^4}\ldots $$
I tried to find the general term but in vain.So do we have to split the sequence into a piece wise function to get the general term.If it is a piece wise fuction how will we solve it to get the convergence?

There is one more doubt there was a question with a representation like this $$\llcorner n $$ What is it actually please explain in detail.I havent encounted it till now.

Comment: I think the notation piece should be a separate question with a bit more context.

Comment: Can't we just club the first two terms and write the general term as  1/2^(2n-1)+1/3^(2n).

Comment: Yes, you should split the series into two (can you prove that it converges absolutely, and so this process produces a viable result?).  It is possible to have a single series term, but it is neither very informative, nor very useful.

Comment: Also that symbol is factorial . it is equivalent to n!.

Comment: @LakshyaGupta: do you have a source?

Comment: Yes it is another question to find convergence..no othe detail.Find the convergence of $\frac{\llcorner n }{n^n}$.Thats it.I cant post a picture bcoz i dont have the required reputation

Comment: @abiessu [factorial@wolframmathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Factorial.html)  "*An older notation for the factorial is...*"

Comment: @JMoravitz: ah, thank you.  Yet another notation I simply haven't seen before.

Comment: @abiessu source for what?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$a_{2n}=\frac {1}{2^{2n+1}}$$
$$a_{2n+1}=\frac {1}{3^{2n+2}} $$

for the sum, use for $|a|<1$,

$$1+a+a^2+a^3+...=\frac {1}{1-a} $$
with $a=1/4$ and $a=1/9$

You should get

$$1/2\frac {1}{1-1/4}+1/9\frac {1}{1-1/9} $$